# How to partition tables by date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

How can i partition rows in SQL Server by date?

### Bonus Chatter

In SQL Server it's relatively easy to partition tables by *year*, e.g.:

- table `Orders_2000`
- table `Orders_2001`
- table `Orders_2002`
- ...
- table `Orders_2011`
- table `Orders_2012`

You create a separate table for each year, making sure to include a `Year` column with a check constraint that matches the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions_1999 (Year int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1999, TransactionID int NOT NULL, CustomerName varchar(50))
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_1999 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions1999 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Year, TransactionID)
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_1999 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions1999_Year CHECK (Year = '1999')

CREATE TABLE Transactions_2000 (Year int NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000, TransactionID int NOT NULL, CustomerName varchar(50))
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2000 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions2000 PRIMARY KEY (Year, TransactionID)
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2000 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions2000_Year CHECK (Year = '2000')

CREATE TABLE Transactions_2001 (Year int NOT NULL DEFAULT 2001, TransactionID int NOT NULL, CustomerName varchar(50))
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2001 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions2001 PRIMARY KEY (Year, TransactionID)
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2001 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions2001_Year CHECK (Year = '2001')
...
CREATE TABLE Transactions_2011 (year int NOT NULL DEFAULT 2011, TransactionID int NOT NULL, CustomerName varchar(50))
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2011 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions2011 PRIMARY KEY (Year, TransactionID)
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2011 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions2011_Year CHECK (Year = '2011')

CREATE TABLE Transactions_2012 (Year int NOT NULL DEFAULT 2012, TransactionID int NOT NULL, CustomerName varchar(50))
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2012 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions2012 PRIMARY KEY (Year, TransactionID)
    ALTER TABLE Transactions_2012 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions2012_Year CHECK (Year = '2012')
```

Then you can construct a `VIEW` that merges to tables together:

```
CREATE VIEW Transactions AS
SELECT * FROM Transactions_1999
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Transactions_2000
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Transactions_2001
UNION ALL
--...
SELECT * FROM Transactions_2011
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Transactions_2012
```

And now you can query this `Transactions` view:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE (CustomerName LIKE 'boyd%')
OR (CustomerName LIKE '% boyd%')
```

And data can be inserted into the view, and SQL Server will automatically put it in the table it's supposed to go in:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions(Year, TransactionID, CustomerName)
VALUES (2012, 378922384, 'Ian Boyd')
```

### But that's not what i want

i want to partitions data into tables by ***age***. Rows with a `TransactionDate` older than 90 days should go into one table, and transactions with a `TransactionDate` newer than 90 days go into another table:

- table `Transactions_olderThan90Days`
- table `Transactions_newerThan90Days`

So says the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions_NewerThan90Days (
    TransactionDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TransactionID int NOT NULL,
    CustomeName varchar(50))


CREATE TABLE Transactions_OlderThan90Days (
    TransactionDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TransactionID int NOT NULL,
    CustomeName varchar(50))
```

Is such a thing possible in SQL Server?

i realize this sounds impossible, since it means SQL Server having to move data constantly.

Comment: Unless you absolutely need that no transaction older than 90 days is in the first table at ANY time I would just settle for a scheduled job that moves all "old" transactions to a different table.

Comment: This isn't possible. You haven't explained what you would hope to gain if it were though.

Comment: @MartinSmith In my real database i would have table `Transactions`, table `Transactions_olderThan90Days`, and the view would be `AllTransactions`. Spontaneously software will only have to deal with 3 months of data, and i can get rid of an entire, complicated, archiving process.

Comment: and are you using SQL 2000 or SQL 2008?  Table partitioning is different than partitioned views.

Comment: Whould you like this moved to data.se?

Comment: @IanBoyd: as per Sam's answer, you'd get a better response on dba.se

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL 2008 you can create table partitions by week or by month depending on how often you would like to switch data. Have a look at parallel processing too, if most of your questions invoke three or four partitions then the same number processors start working in parallel for your answers. 
(I would not advise to use partitions by day, because the limit of 1000 partitions is then reached within 3 years).